# Existe alguna manera de mandar datos de Python a Arduino sin meter tantos retardos?

Tags: python, arduino, serialport

Tengo una duda, estoy trabajando con unos programas para mandar datos de Python hacia Arduino y poder mover 2 servomotores, el problema es ocupo eliminar el tiempo de espera para mandar el siguiente dato desde Python pero no logro hacerlo, estaba pensando en mandar un vector de datos tipo [101,201,501,901,1101] y que los pueda leer el Arduino y de esta forma mover el servomotor pero no se como, si me pudieran orientar.

En este caso estoy mandando datos por ejemplo el 501 para mover el servomotor 1 a 50 grados, después un tiempo de espera y mandar el siguiente dato, este tiempo de espera es el que quiero eliminar pero no puedo ya que si se lo quito ya no envía los siguiente datos

Este es el código que estoy usando en Python :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import serial
import time
#Se inicializa el puerto Serial a 9600 baudios
arduino = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600, timeout=0.1)


while True: #Creamos el ciclo infinito
    
    numero = input("Dame un núero: ") 

    if numero == '1':
        arduino.write(str(501).encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.write(str(1001).encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.write(str(11).encode())
        #arduino.close()
        #time.sleep(1)
 
    elif numero == '2':
        arduino.write(str(502).encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.write(str(802).encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.write(str(1102).encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        arduino.write(str(12).encode())
   
    elif numero == '5':
        break
```

El programa de Arduino para leer los datos enviados por Python es el siguiente:

```
//Creamos los objetos servo
Servo servo;
Servo servo2;
 
int enviado; //Aqui enviamos el numero completo
int num; //Numero del servo
int posicion; //Posicion del servo
int a;
 
void setup()
{
  //Inicializamos los Servos
  servo.attach(14);
  servo2.attach(16);
  
  //Inicializamos la comunicacion por Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  a=1;
}
 
void loop()
{

  if (a<=1)
  {
  servo.write(0);
  servo2.write(0);
  Serial.print("Aun \n");
  delay(500);
  a=a+1;
  }


  else
  {
  
  if(Serial.available() >= 1)
  {
 
    enviado = Serial.parseInt(); //Leer entero por serial
    num = enviado%10; // Extraer el num del motor
    enviado = enviado/10; //Dividir el entero entre 10
    posicion = enviado; //Guardar el angulo
     
    //Hora de mover los servos!
    if(num == 1)
    {
      servo.write(posicion);
    }
    else if(num == 2)
    {
      servo2.write(posicion);
    }
  }
  //delay(500);
  //servo.write(0);
  //servo2.write(0);
  }
  
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, saludos:

Que tengas un excelente día

Answer (score 3):

La raíz del problema es que falta un delimitador tras cada valor enviado.

Cuando haces `Serial.parseInt()`, Arduino comienza a leer y juntar dígitos hasta encontrar algo que **no** sea un dígito. Entonces hace la conversión.

Si no detecta ese caracter, entonces espera hasta que le de TIME OUT, que es 1 segundo por default. El time-out que rige es el fijado en el Arduino; el time-out en Python es irrelevante, ya que ese código no lee la puerta serial.

La solución es agregar un caracter no numérico al terminar de enviar el entero. Por costumbre, enviare un '\n'.

El código Python se puede simplificar definiendo una función que envía una lista de valores recibidos como parámetro

```
def enviar(lista):
    for valor in lista:
        arduino.write(str(valor).encode())
        arduino.write('\n'.encode())
```

Nota que la función no tiene ningun `sleep`.

```
# Se inicializa el puerto Serial a 9600 baudios
arduino = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600, timeout=0.1)

while True:  # Creamos el ciclo infinito

    numero = input("Dame un número: ")

    if numero == '1':
        enviar([501, 1001, 11])
    elif numero == '2':
        enviar([502, 802, 1102, 12])
    elif numero == '5':
        break
```

[En mi caso, la puerta serial del PC es ttyACMO.]

Del lado del Arduino no tengo servos para probar, así que los sustituí por dos LED conectados a puertas PWM. La posición del servo es representada por la intensidad del LED.

```
int enviado; //Aqui enviamos el numero completo
int num; //Numero del servo
int posicion; //Posicion del servo

#define servo1 5
#define servo2 6
```

Nota que puedo posicionar los "servos" a cero en `setup`, eliminando la necesidad de la variable `a` original.

```
void setup()
{
  //Inicializamos la comunicacion por Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(servo1, OUTPUT); # servo1.attach(14)
  pinMode(servo2, OUTPUT); # servo2.attach(16)

  analogWrite(servo1, 0); # servo1.write(0)
  analogWrite(servo2, 0); # servo2.write(0)
}
```

El loop se reduce a

```
void loop()
{    
  if (Serial.available() >= 1) {
    enviado = Serial.parseInt(); //Leer entero por serial
    num = enviado % 10; // Extraer el num del motor
    enviado = enviado / 10; //Dividir el entero entre 10
    posicion = enviado; //Guardar el angulo

    //Hora de mover los servos!
    if (num == 1) {
      analogWrite(servo1, posicion); # servo1.write(posicion)
    }
    else if (num == 2) {
      analogWrite(servo2, posicion); # servo2.write(posicion)
    }
  }
}
```

Por supuesto, tendrás que reconvertir los `analogWrite` por `servo.write`.